# JEMETER Non-GUI : missing class com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.ConversionException error

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-3.2

I am creating a JMeter test plan from scratch.
Here is my code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        StandardJMeterEngine jmeterEngine = new StandardJMeterEngine();
        JMeterUtils.setJMeterHome("/Users/myDir/Documents/JMeter/apache-jmeter-3.3");
        JMeterUtils.loadJMeterProperties("src/main/resources/jmeter.properties");
        JMeterUtils.initLocale();

        //create test plan
        TestPlan testPlan = new TestPlan();
        testPlan.setEnabled(true);
        testPlan.setName("Test Plan");

        //create thread group
        ThreadGroup threadGroup = new ThreadGroup();
        threadGroup.setNumThreads(1);
        threadGroup.setRampUp(1);

        // create http sampler
        HTTPSampler httpSampler = new HTTPSampler();
        httpSampler.setProtocol("https");
        httpSampler.setDomain("myDomain.services.company.com");
        httpSampler.setPath("ims/login/v1/token");
        httpSampler.setMethod("POST"); 
        httpSampler.setFollowRedirects(true);
        httpSampler.setAutoRedirects(false);
        httpSampler.setUseKeepAlive(true);
        httpSampler.addArgument("client_id", "argValue1");
        httpSampler.addArgument("scope", "argValue2");
        httpSampler.addArgument("userName", "abc%2B249%40gmail.com");
        httpSampler.addArgument("password", "Abc123"); 

        //Add sampler to the thread group
        threadGroup.addTestElement(httpSampler);

        HashTree testPlanHashTree = new HashTree();
        testPlanHashTree.add(testPlan);
        testPlanHashTree.add(threadGroup);

        // Generating the JMX file
        SaveService.saveTree(testPlanHashTree, new FileOutputStream(JMeterUtils.getJMeterHome() + "/bin/Test2.jmx"));
    }
```

When I execute this code my Test2.jmx is created.

Next I try to run Test2.jmx through non-GUI mode of Jmeter by using the following command:

./jmeter.sh -n -t Test2.jmx

Instead of running  my test plan Jmeter throws the following error:

```
Error in NonGUIDriver java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Problem loading XML from:'/Users/chandrat/Documents/JMeter/apache-jmeter-3.3/bin/Test2.jmx', missing class com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.ConversionException: 
---- Debugging information ----
cause-exception     : com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.ConversionException
cause-message       : 
first-jmeter-class  : org.apache.jmeter.save.converters.HashTreeConverter.unmarshal(HashTreeConverter.java:67)
class               : org.apache.jmeter.save.ScriptWrapper
required-type       : org.apache.jmeter.threads.ThreadGroup
converter-type      : org.apache.jmeter.save.ScriptWrapperConverter
path                : /jmeterTestPlan/org.apache.jorphan.collections.HashTree/org.apache.jorphan.collections.HashTree/ThreadGroup
line number         : 6
version             : 3.3 r1808647
-------------------------------
```

1) I am not sure how to resolve this? Cause-message is blank? What should I do so that my test plan gets executed without the error above?

2) Can you also take a look at my test plan generation code? Is that code right? Should the testGroup be added directly to the tree or to the test plan first and then the test plan should be added to the tree?

Here are the dependencies from my pom file, in case I am missing a jar.

```
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.jmeter</groupId>
        <artifactId>ApacheJMeter_core</artifactId>
        <version>3.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.jmeter</groupId>
        <artifactId>jorphan</artifactId>
        <version>3.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.jmeter</groupId>
        <artifactId>ApacheJMeter_http</artifactId>
        <version>3.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>2.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        <version>3.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>oro</groupId>
        <artifactId>oro</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.8</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.avalon.framework</groupId>
        <artifactId>avalon-framework-api</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
```

Please help. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to be able to open the generated test plan in JMeter GUI you need to define a little bit more properties, amend your code to look like:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    StandardJMeterEngine jmeterEngine = new StandardJMeterEngine();
    JMeterUtils.setJMeterHome("/Users/myDir/Documents/JMeter/apache-jmeter-3.3");
    JMeterUtils.loadJMeterProperties("src/main/resources/jmeter.properties");
    JMeterUtils.initLocale();

    //create test plan
    TestPlan testPlan = new TestPlan();
    testPlan.setEnabled(true);
    testPlan.setName("Test Plan");
    testPlan.setProperty(TestElement.TEST_CLASS, TestPlan.class.getName());
    testPlan.setProperty(TestElement.GUI_CLASS, TestPlanGui.class.getName());
    testPlan.setUserDefinedVariables((Arguments) new ArgumentsPanel().createTestElement());

    LoopController loopController = new LoopController();
    loopController.setLoops(1);
    loopController.setFirst(true);
    loopController.setProperty(TestElement.TEST_CLASS, LoopController.class.getName());
    loopController.setProperty(TestElement.GUI_CLASS, LoopControlPanel.class.getName());
    loopController.initialize();

    //create thread group
    ThreadGroup threadGroup = new ThreadGroup();
    threadGroup.setNumThreads(1);
    threadGroup.setRampUp(1);
    threadGroup.setSamplerController(loopController);
    threadGroup.setProperty(TestElement.TEST_CLASS, ThreadGroup.class.getName());
    threadGroup.setProperty(TestElement.GUI_CLASS, ThreadGroupGui.class.getName());

    // create http sampler
    HTTPSampler httpSampler = new HTTPSampler();
    httpSampler.setProtocol("https");
    httpSampler.setDomain("myDomain.services.company.com");
    httpSampler.setPath("ims/login/v1/token");
    httpSampler.setMethod("POST");
    httpSampler.setFollowRedirects(true);
    httpSampler.setAutoRedirects(false);
    httpSampler.setUseKeepAlive(true);
    httpSampler.addArgument("client_id", "argValue1");
    httpSampler.addArgument("scope", "argValue2");
    httpSampler.addArgument("userName", "abc%2B249%40gmail.com");
    httpSampler.addArgument("password", "Abc123");
    httpSampler.setProperty(TestElement.TEST_CLASS, HTTPSampler.class.getName());
    httpSampler.setProperty(TestElement.GUI_CLASS, HttpTestSampleGui.class.getName());

    //Add sampler to the thread group

    HashTree testPlanHashTree = new HashTree();
    HashTree threadGroupHashTree = testPlanHashTree.add(testPlan, threadGroup);
    threadGroupHashTree.add(httpSampler);

    // Generating the JMX file
    SaveService.saveTree(testPlanHashTree, new FileOutputStream(JMeterUtils.getJMeterHome() + "/bin/Test2.jmx"));
}
```

References:

- [JMeter API](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/)
- [Five Ways To Launch a JMeter Test without Using the JMeter GUI](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/5-ways-launch-jmeter-test-without-using-jmeter-gui)
- [jmeter-from-code](https://bitbucket.org/blazemeter/jmeter-from-code/) example project

Comment: Thank you Dmitri. Your code works. I am new to Jmeter so I have a few questions which will clarify my concepts more: 1) Can you explain the lines about the hash tree? (I know what a hash tree is, but )why and how is it being used here? Why do we need testPlanHashTree and threadGroupHashTree separately? what is happening is this line: HashTree threadGroupHashTree = testPlanHashTree.add(testPlan, threadGroup);? Next if I need to add an element, like HeaderManager to my httpSampler will I have to create a separate hashtree for my httpSampler. Where would my header manager get added?

Comment: Next if I need to add an element, like HeaderManager to my httpSampler will I have to create a separate hashtree for my httpSampler. Where would my header manager get added?